# How can we block a website in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I often get annoying websites pop up (they bypassed Chrome's pop up block). I tried using adblocker's custom filter to block them.

For example, I wrote:

```
||someDomain.com^$document
```

Sadly it doesn't work. Is there other way I can block website in Chrome?

Note: I tried website block, and it does block the website but the new tab still pops out. I want to prevent the new tab from popping out.

Comment: You could block it from your hosts file by putting an entry in it like freewebcams.com 127.0.0.1. But this doesn't block for JUST chrome. Although this 'hack' has become somewhat of a joke I think...not sure why...

Comment: I could but note: I want to prevent the new tab from popping out. Blocking the site will not prevent it from popping out. It just gives you a blank pop out page.